# [webpack-dev-server]Why even I haven't used HotModuleReplacementPlugin or set "hot:true",HMR is happen?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I've been learning webpack-dev-server recently, **the webpack documentation tells me that** when I try to implement HMR(hot-moudle-replacement),**I should use devServer.hot to "Enable webpack's Hot Module Replacement feature",just like this:**

```
module.exports = {
   /*other thing ...*/
  hot:true
}
```

and the documentation also tells me that **"Note that you must also include a new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() to fully enable HMR"**
just like this:

```
 plugins:[
   new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
 ]
```

**but! even I don't used  the two methods mentioned above, the HMR still work!!!for CSS,JS event JSX**

**I am very confused**

Comment: and I could not disable HMR with set "hot:false"

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're not [confusing hot reloading with live reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429055/4447841).

Secondly, check your `webpack-dev-server` options. Do you have `--inline --hot` included?

Finally, take a look at your Babel presets. I'm using `babel-preset-react-hmre` which results in the following [DevTools Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCAeb.png).