# What is it called when you are programming and a program automatically updates your changes when you save changes to a file?

Tags: workflow, terminology

When programming there is a workflow that works like:

1. Change a file and save it.
2. The a compiler or interpreter.
3. Look at the result.

But there is also a workflow that goes like this:
(actually it is similar to working with this stack overflow question Window I am typing into)

1. Start a program that watches a directory of files for changes.
2. Change a file and save it.
3. The results immediately appear as the program runs the compiler and updates the program (usually in a browser) immediately.

I'm looking for what the second workflow is generally referred to as.

Comment: I think the only single word I've ever heard that describes this is "interactive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic deployment of source code changes is referred to by few different terms:

- [hot reloading](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)
- [auto reloading](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayConsole#Running-the-server-in-development-mode)
- [live reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428954/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-reloading-and-live-reloading-in-react-native)
- [triggered restart](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver#triggered-restart)
- [triggered execution](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Triggered-Execution.html)

Personally, I hear the term *hot reloading* most frequently.