# Need to restart computer when developping

Tags: react-native

I try to make apps in react native (not with expo, I created my code with react-native init and run with react-native run-android) and when I make changes in the code they are not always taken into account : to take them into account I have to restart computer.

I have to do it several times a day, it is time consuming. I have tested to remove to app tested from the device, to make yarn cache clean, but it doesn't work, the only thing that works is to restart (I am using a Mac if it makes a difference).

Is there a command I can make to reset a cache that I don't know and save previous state of my app ?

Comment: Did you try to delete the build directory in android/app?

Comment: @Mukeyii : It doesn't solve the problem (I deleted only build folder not build.gradle (I don't know if I should))

Answer (score -1):

You may have a caching issue, try the cache clearing solutions in this link

[How to clear react-native cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache)

And also, you may want to try the Hot Reloading or Live Reloading options in the dev menu.

[What is the difference between Hot Reloading and Live Reloading in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428954/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-reloading-and-live-reloading-in-react-native)