# Docker volume updated on container after changes, but nothing happen in host

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-volume

I use volume between host and container for a flask application. The web part of my docker-compose looks like this:

```
  web:
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "docker/Dockerfile.web"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - database:/var/run/postgresql
      - .:/usr/src/app
volumes:
  database:
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "./sources/app.py"]
```

I think my volumes are well created because when I make and update in `app.py` from the host, the `app.py` from the container is also updated. **But the problem is when I reload the page from my browser the content has not been updated**.

When I do `docker volume list` I got this:

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               b26d14737c65ba4d26c3751ae898883e9062c4894a5fd31b191ffd9ded7f1d50
local               web-app_database
```

What is the volume b26d14 ? I don't think it's one a created with docker-compose. After running `docker volume inspect` it returns:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-03-21T10:41:19Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b26d14737c65ba4d26c3751ae898883e9062c4894a5fd31b191ffd9ded7f1d50/_data",
        "Name": "b26d14737c65ba4d26c3751ae898883e9062c4894a5fd31b191ffd9ded7f1d50",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

The only way I have to make it works it is to restart the container.

I found this article: [link](https://medium.com/@xavier.priour/docker-mounted-files-not-updating-38a10049d797) but it did not fix my issue.

Docker versions:
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
- docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

Any ideas ?

Thanks for replies and have a nice day.

Comment: When your application code changes, are you restarting your container?

Comment: When I make a code change in host app.py I got the same change in container app.py. Without restarting anything. But when I reload the page from my browser, I don't see any change.

Comment: Sounds like a probelm with your app responding to the new content, rather than a docker problem.

Comment: Maybe. I tried to run the app without cache. Flask has an option to disable it. But I still have the problem. Have you seen the article I linked ?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you post you Dockerfile, so that we can see how do you run your app?

Comment: I edited the post with my Dockerfile

Comment: How do you refresh your browser? F5 or CTRL + SHIFT + R or clicking in your address bar, removing the fragment and hit ENTER?

Comment: I do command + R.

Comment: Try setting `FLASK_ENV` in Dockerfile with `ENV FLASK_ENV=development`. That will enable app reloading when something is changed.

Comment: This worked ! So I know it's a Flask problem now. Why does Flask need to reload the application to display the changes ?

Comment: Even in local development, you need to restart the app to see changes. That's why most of the frameworks support some sort of [live or hot reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429055/4778343) to speed up development. In your case, flask provides this feature when you [set FLASK_ENV](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#debug-mode) environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through comments, we concluded that the issue was how Flask handles live/hot reloading and has nothing to do with Docker.

Flask provides [`FLASK_ENV`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#debug-mode) environment variable that can be used to enable *development features* such as debugger and automatic reloader. To enable development features you need to set its value to `development`.

Docker also provides a neat way to set environment variables with [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) keyword. All you have to do is to add the following line in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
```

Comment: Wonderful! Works like a charm. Thanks, mate!